# Invalid character value for cast specification sometimes

Tags: sql, vb6

Im currently investigating a bug that just happens sometimes. I have not been able to see any patterns to the behavior yet. I have a vb6 com+-application that communicates with the server.

```
Err: Invalid character value for cast specification. (&H80040E21)
Src: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server
Stacktrace:
GetClientRS("SELECT * FROM Visit where GUID=?")
GetVisit("('{5EF4A26A-0909-4371-97F7-A2597CB7ADE3}')")
```

This is the error that happens sometimes. Maybe 1-2 times for every 5 times it is called. I have tried a trace in SQL server profiler but I am unable to detect any errors.

Does anyone have any ideas I could try?

```
Edit:
Code for calling the command:
GetVisit:
    Set cmd = CreateCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.per_Visit WHERE GUID=?")
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter(, adGUID, , , SafeGUID(sGUID))

    Set GetVisit = GetClientRS(cmd, True)

SafeGUID:
     If Mid$(sGUID, 1, 1) <> "{" Then                                  
         sGUID = "{" & sGUID & "}"                                     
    End If

   SafeGUID = sGUID
```

Comment: Look at [Passing a GUID value from command line ...](http://blogs.technet.com/b/anurag_sharma/archive/2008/02/20/passing-a-guid-value-from-command-line-using-dtexec-to-a-variable-to-be-used-as-a-parameter-in-oledb-source-query-in-ssis-package-fails-with-invalid-character-value-for-cast-specification.aspx)

Comment: I considered that, but doesn't explain why it happens sometimes and not all the time.

Comment: It seems that a GUID is sometimes not formated properly. Is the one you are presenting just an example or the one really causing exception?

Comment: This is just one example of the exception. Happens with other GUIDS too but not all.

Comment: Would you add code for passing parameter to command? It is a guess only but parameter can be truncated.

Comment: sGUID = "('{5EF4A26A-0909-4371-97F7-A2597CB7ADE3}')" ?

Comment: Yes that should be the value passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SafeGUID` function is probably not clever enough.

When

```
sGUID = "('{5EF4A26A-0909-4371-97F7-A2597CB7ADE3}')"
```

the value actually passed as parameter is

```
{('{5EF4A26A-0909-4371-97F7-A2597CB7ADE3}')}
```

which is not a valid GUID.

Comment: Thanks.. got any suggestion for a better safeguid function or a function to "clean" the guid?

Comment: Am I right? I is possible to put a breakpoint to SafeGUID and check.  Cleaning is dependent on the way you suppose it the value is corrupt. You can use something as `sGUID = Mid$(sGUID, 4, 38)` or an ugly chain of replace for or unwanted characters or a regular expression (if you manage to call it in VB6)

Comment: Yeah you were right. Still not sure why it was malformed, but did a cleaning before it's called and no more errors.